# How to launch a program's editor in "admin-mode" from context menu in explorer?

Tags: windows-7

The problem is Windows' well-known Vista-style security dialogs.

The files in the `C:\inetpub` folder are "protected". So to edit them, the editor program needs to be launched using "admin-mode" (Ctrl+Shift+Enter from Start menu), and then the desired file is to be opened via the editor's File->Open. This works.

But I want to be able to right-click on a file (text file, document, etc.) in the `C:\inetpub` directory in Windows Explorer and have the associated editor program launch automatically in "admin-mode".

Is this possible?

Comment: You could instead give your user account permission to edit `c:\inetpub`.  Just right-click on `inetpub` from the root of the `C:` drive, go to the *Security* tab, click *Edit*, and add your user account to the list and give it *Full Control*.  Then you won't need to elevate to edit files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down `SHIFT` and `RIGHT-CLICK` the app (.exe, .bat...) file you want to run. Select Run as Administrator from the context menu

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not what I want to do (run EXE etc.)

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is right click on the executable file, click properties, select the "compatability tab", and check the box at the bottom that says "run as administrator"

Comment: good god, whoever downvoted this is an idiot.

Comment: @Patches answer worked for me. Before you go around calling names, re-read the question. I'm sure that'll clear things up for you. And welcome to SO.